# Lenovo thinkpad t450s slow to log in

Tags: windows-7, laptop, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop

I'm a proud new owner of Lenovo t450s. This laptop is really great, beautiful and powerful.

But I have a major problem with it. It takes ages to open the login screen! Either when I lock the computer with <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or when it boots, I must wait almost 30 seconds on a blank screen until my user icon and the password text area appear.

I'm running Windows 7 Pro (with all the junkware pre-installed by Lenovo). Do you have any solutions to this problem? It would be really great.

My config:

- Intel Core i7 5600U@2.6 GHz
- 8 GB ram
- A Samsung SSD (I don't know the model, but I have 7.9 in the harddrive section in Windows performance test)

Comment: Can you check for any errors reported in Event Viewer? You might also want to check and uninstall any Credential Manager or Finger-print software that is installed and see if that help (just a hunch). These usually come installed with Lenovo

Comment: in my case, fingerprint software makes the delay, i lot indeed

Comment: I thought to uninstall the fingerprint software, indeed, but was scared it would break something. Can I do it safely ?

Comment: Yes, it's safe. Alternatively you can try only disabling it (or the service), then restarting the PC.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I desinstalled the Lenovo fingerprint manager (like any other program), and my computer boot and lock really fast now ! Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Xavierjazz Why is this not an answer? It was posted by the OP as the solution to his slow startup and unlock problem.

Answer (score 1):

A 30 second boot time is relatively quick, depending on the hardware in the computer. If you are using an SSD (Solid State Drive), your boot and wake up time should be significantly less. This is because there are no moving parts and even if the drive were to "sleep," there is virtually zero traditional spin-up time.

This question is a little bit arbitrary because if you are using energy-efficient hardware, such as a mobile processor, a "green" drive, and/or a typical 5400RPM laptop platter drive, it appears that your boot time is average. It's also important to consider whether you put the computer to sleep or into hibernation. These have drastically different wake-up times.

My first suggestion would be to remove any unnecessary junkware that you've mentioned. If this is running in the background and taking processor time, it's bound to slow the computer down. You may also want to consider testing the computer when it's running on battery and when it's running on an AC adapter, and also checking its power vs performance settings. I'm not familiar with the motherboards used by Lenovo, but in my ASUS motherboard, you can tweak the power settings in BIOS -- this will drastically change the performance of the computer. Since most laptops are set to energy-saving settings by default, this could be the cause.

To edit the power settings within Windows, open up **Control Panel > Power Options > Power Plans**. You can tweak it on the OS-level from here. What you may want to change, in particular, is the hard drive spin-down time. You can access this by clicking **Change Plan Settings > Change Advanced Power Settings > Hard Disk > Turn Off Hard Disk After** and set it to 0, which will disable hard drive spin-down. If this does not cause a noticeable change, browse the BIOS.

Comment: I will try the performance settings. But, it's not just a boot when the computer is slow. Even when I lock the screen (windows + L) it takes several seconds (15-20) at the blue screen where it's written Windows 7, but without my user icon and the place where you can enter your password. I don't know if you understand me, but I'm not a native speaker and I don't know the good words to say it